# JVM crashing with VBOs using LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, jvm, lwjgl, vbo

Every time I try to run my LWJGL application the JVM crashes. It seems to be related to adding multiple triangles to my VBO.

Here is my initialization code

```
float[] vertices = {
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,

    0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f
};

vertexCount = vertices.length / 3;

FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
verticesBuffer.flip();

vboId = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexPointer(vertexCount, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And this is my rendering code

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);   
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

When I remove the last 9 values in the vertices array it works fine, but if I keep those, or add more, the JVM will crash.

Comment: you do `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` before `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);` ? That doesn't seem right you need to have your buffer bound.

Comment: I didn't notice that. It still displayed without binding it somehow but when I made it bind the buffer in the render loop it didn't change anything.

Comment: @PeterT: The buffer does not have to be bound during the draw call. It needs to be bound when `glVertexPointer` is called, which it is in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `glVertexPointer` is the number of coordinates per vertex, not the number of vertices. So change that line to this:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
```

Comment: Thanks! The answers are always the smallest things, it would seem.